HVAC create a DIY Arduino smart thermostat, AC current no control board
I have a HVAC that seem to have no control board in the ceiling near the AC unit. The thermostat is directly connected to 6 wires that measure 220V AC (see picture). When I looked for the control board at the HVAC in the ceiling, no board was found and the wires seem to directly go to the fan and AC valve, measuring again 220v AC.
My plan is to connect relays and a rectifier unit to change the current to DC and 24V so I can power a ESP32 Arduino so I can create my own smart thermostat. Would this be possible?


Yes, this would be possible.

Please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. It's word soup. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Yes, this is possible. However, custom thermostats at line voltage do not meet code in many places in the world, and would be a nightmare for insurance coverage and for subsequent owner/occupants of your home. For this reason, commercial smart thermostats are usually preferred.

damn didn't even think of that, thanks! Ill reconsider :)

Does your unit accept IR control? If so, an Arduino or other microcontroller (I am using a set of Raspberry  Pis) set up as an IR transmitter can take over control, with proper programming. And since it isn't connected, it is not only safer, it has no risk of voiding warranty.
